# Getting "Failed to apply web.config modifications" in Sharepoint Central Admininstration when trying to create a web application

Tags: sharepoint, configuration, sharepoint-2010

I try to add a new web application in sharepoint central administration and get the following error message:

> Failed to apply web.config modifications to file 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories\9675\web.config'. 
>   Failed to apply a web.config modification to file 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories\9675\web.config'.  The specified node "configuration/system.webserver/modules" was not found in the web.config file

The same error appears when trying to run any Shell-Command that changes something in the web.config. I already tried to do a repair-installation of sharepoint with no afford.

Any idea what could cause this error?

Comment: "solved" this by reinstalling the machine...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the quickest solution and the problem is happening on a testing web application just delete it and re-create it again. The new web application should have a clean web.config and you cana play again.

Otherwise you could be cleaning the web.config file manually and checking if your changes would help or not.

Also, make sure that you **do not change web application root directory by editing settings in IIS**. After doing thit SP runs fine but you'll get into trouble when maitaining features and solutions. SharePoint has this value in the database; you'd have to synchronize it with IIS using its object model.